# Elasticsearch aggregation query in elastic.js

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elasticjs

I have a hard time translating `aggregation query` for elastic search into `elastic.js.` I am reading the documentation but I just can not figure it out. And the examples that you can find online are mostly about deprecated facets feature, that is not very useful. 
The JSON for example aggregation is as follows:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "foo": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query": {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "shape": [
                  "wc"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "field": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "shape",
            "size": 10,
            "exclude": {
              "pattern": []
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: could you verify if this is the right query?

Comment: I am not es expert so I am sending the query to it to see it it is valid and yes it is valid and working as expected, where as the query proposed by Or Weinberger does not work. As I understand it to have filter for your aggregation, it has to be 'in side' of the aggregation. Where as the 'query' filed is out side of it but it has bit different syntax than filter one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would nest `terms aggregation` into `filter aggregation` with `elasticjs`

```
ejs.Request()
    .size(0)
    .agg(ejs.FilterAggregation("foo").filter(ejs.BoolFilter()
            .must(ejs.TermsFilter('shape', 'wc'))
            .must(ejs.QueryFilter(ejs.QueryStringQuery().query("*"))))
              .agg(ejs.TermsAggregation("field").field("shape").size(10).exclude("my_pattern"))
        )
```

BTW you are filtering on `shape` and then doing `aggregations` on it. I am not sure what exactly you are trying.

I found their [documentation](http://docs.fullscale.co/elasticjs/ejs.TermsAggregation.html) pretty good, Also they have a great [tool](http://docs.fullscale.co/translator/#) to check if your query is valid and right. This would help you a lot

Hope this helps!!

Comment: So it is not 100 % what I need it pointed me in right direction.

Comment: So is it possible to express the original query in elastic.js ?

Comment: It is possible,  I have edited my answer pls have a look, also query string is not necessary, it is selecting everything

Comment: Thanks for the tool thing it is very useful

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have misplaced your query under the `aggs` element. Try this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "shape": [
              "wc"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "foo": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "shape",
        "size": 10,
        "exclude": {
          "pattern": []
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I have tried that ( elasticsearch 1.7 ) and it is returning  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], it is working when I replace root level 'query' with 'filter'.  Anyway the question was about elastic.js syntax